# Flatten group of multiple fields in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to get the sum of amounts grouped by address and date:

```
db.coolCollection.aggregate([ 
{ $group: 
  { _id : 
    { address:"$address", 
      date: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$block.time"}}}}, 
  sum : { $sum:{ "$amount" }}} ])
```

Great, except the results look like this:

```
{
  _id: {
    address: "abc123",
    date: 2021-03-22T00:00:00.000+00:00
  },
  sum: 48645
}
```

I want this:

```
{
  address: "abc123",
  date: 2021-03-22T00:00:00.000+00:00,
  sum: 48645
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you'd just add a `$project` stage to restructure, here is how to do is using `$replaceRoot` under the assumption the `_id` can contain many fields you don't want to manually convert:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$_id",
          "$$ROOT"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Rwyw_Ro9O1x)